# Comment About Matrix Exponentials in Rossman's Book

Tags: matrices

Wulf Rossman, in his book on Lie groups, makes a "remark" on page 4 that the following conditions are equivalent:

(a) X and Y are commuting square matrices
(b) exp(sX) and exp(tY) commute for all real s and t
(c) exp(sX + tY) = exp(sX)exp(tY)

He apparently views this as easy. The implication "a implies b" certainly is, and I can prove the implication "c implies a" (in fact I can prove it if we just assume s = t), but the implication "b implies c" eludes me. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's also easy (or relatively easy, I suppose) to show that a implies c, which means that it's also sufficient to show b implies a

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to show that b implies a, which as I note in my comment is a reasonable approach here.

From b, we can deduce that for all $s,t$, we have
$$
\exp(sX)\exp(tY) = \exp(tY)\exp(sX).
$$
Taking the derivatives on both sides with respect to $s$ and plugging in $s = 0$ gives us
$$
X \exp(t Y) = \exp(tY) X,
$$
which holds for all real $t$. We can similarly take a derivative on both sides with respect to $t$ and plug in $t = 0$ to reach the conclusion that $XY = YX$, as desired.